# Spring 5 MVC not finding mapping to controller returning JSON

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring 5, and I've been studying all the different sites about Spring 5 MVC, learning as much as possible, but still can't get a response to "http://localhost/[webcontext]/secure/json/organizations". I end up with this: [o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND. I can tell that the class is loaded and autowiring complete as I had to fix those problems.
Below is my code. What am I missing or doing wrong?

EnrollmentRestController.java

```
package c.i.i.w.e.controllers;

@RestController
public class EnrollmentRestController extends AbstractIfactoryController
{
  @GetMapping(path = "/secure/json/organizations", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public QueryResults<OrganizationQueryResult> execute() throws ApplicationException
  {
    return super.getEnrollmentService().findOrganizations();
  }
}
```

ApplicationInitializer.java:

```
package c.i.i.w.e.config;

@Configuration
@EntityScan("c.i.i.w.e")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"c.i.i.w.e"})
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
  static final String PU_NAME                 = "i";
  static final String SERVLET_MAPPING         = "/";
  static final String SERVLET_NAME            = "spring";

  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
  {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(PU_NAME);

    return entityManagerFactory;
  }

  private void newAppServlet(
    ServletContext servletContext,
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext)
  {
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(appContext);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet(SERVLET_NAME,
      dispatcherServlet);

    appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    appServlet.addMapping(SERVLET_MAPPING);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartup(
    ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
  {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    appContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);
    appContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
    appContext.refresh();

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));

    newAppServlet(servletContext, appContext);
  }
}
```

DispatcherConfig.java

```
package c.i.i.w.e.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class DispatcherConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
    DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
  {
    configurer.enable();
  }

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(
    ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)
  {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(
    PathMatchConfigurer configurer)
  {
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(
    ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
  {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
  }

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver()
  {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    
    return bean;
  }
}
```

Here's the last few lines from the log file

```
2020-08-26 16:13:50,566 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] GET "/ifactory-enroll/images/ICU_Logo_New_Blue.png", parameters={}
2020-08-26 16:13:50,566 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Mapped to org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@f3bb1d
2020-08-26 16:13:50,567 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Completed 304 NOT_MODIFIED
2020-08-26 16:13:56,047 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] GET "/ifactory-enroll/secure/json/organizations", parameters={}
2020-08-26 16:13:56,048 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] Mapped to org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@f3bb1d
2020-08-26 16:13:56,049 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: I think that I see part of the problem. According to the log file, the "/ifactory-enroll/secure/json/organizations" URL is mapped to the DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler, which handles static content like CSS and JS files. So I think I need to get it mapped to the DispatcherServlet. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which changed fixed this, but here's the end results that now work.

ApplicationInitializer.java

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
  static final String BASE_PACKAGES   = "c.i.i.web.enroll";
  static final String PU_NAME         = "i";
  static final String SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";
  static final String SERVLET_NAME    = "spring";

  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
  {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(PU_NAME);

    return entityManagerFactory;
  }

  private void newAppServlet(
    ServletContext servletContext)
  {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher;

    dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);
    
    dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext);
    
    dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(SERVLET_NAME, dispatcherServlet);
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping(SERVLET_MAPPING);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartup(
    ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
  {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    newAppServlet(servletContext);
  }
}
```

DispatcherConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"c.i.i.web.enroll"})
public class DispatcherConfig implements  WebMvcConfigurer 
{
  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
    DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
  {
    configurer.enable();
  }

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(
    ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)
  {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void configurePathMatch(
    PathMatchConfigurer configurer)
  {
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
  }


  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(
    ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
  {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
  }

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver()
  {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    
    return viewResolver;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What's your local server's port? Don't you have a port number such as http://localhost:portNumber/secure/json/organizations You can try 8080 or other defaults depending on your local server.

Comment: I'm using WebLogic with Apache. The port number's not a problem as I've gotten Struts1 webapps to work the same way. Also, there's other resources, like CSS files, that I can see from the log file that the DispatcherServlet is getting correctly. The DispatcherServlet seems to be getting my request, as the log file shows " [o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND" for that URL.

Comment: So you're sure that your local server's port is 80. Then try adding @ResponseBody annotation to your controller method. Can you share the log output also?

Comment: I had @@ResponseBody in there before when I was using @@Controller. But then I decided to use @@RestController and the docs said that I didn't need @@ResponseBody anymore. Anyways, I tried it with @@ResponseBody again and got the same results. I add the last few lines of the log file to the main post.

Comment: Sorry for the "@@" but SO was getting annoyed by using a single "@"

Comment: /ifactory-enroll/secure/json/organizations OR secure/json/organizations? Because the log says that your get request is for /ifactory-enroll/secure/json/organizations

Comment: /ifactory-enroll is the web app context. So the URLs will always be localhost/ifactory-enroll/something